# find max in each cell of multiple DataFrame Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have about 2000 similar DataFrames (DF1,DF2,....,DF2000) with same shape ( names of columns and index).
I want to get max and min values in each cells (same positions).
I could iterate by column names and index to verify but it would be very slow. What's the best way to do such task ?
Example:

```
columns = ['A','B','C','D']
for i in range(4):
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(4, 4)),columns=columns)
```

[image: 4 similar DF]
I need max values DF with

> `DF_max[0,'A] = 78`

and min values DF with

> `DF_min[0,'A'] = 10`

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have all the df in a list

```
l=[df1,df2,df3.....]

DF=pd.concat(l,keys=range(len(l))).groupby(level=1)

maxdf=DF.max()
mindf=DF.min()
```